# Checked "Require a password reset on next login" on my account, can't log in anymore

Tags: password

As a test, I checked the "Require a password reset on next login" box for my account and then logged out.

I tried logging in, expecting some sort of password reset screen, but nothing happened.

I then tried to reset my password at the login screen -- something I was able to do before -- and nothing happened.

In both cases, I get a "500 (Internal Server Error)" in the console.

Any ideas for fixing this? At the very least, can I just reset my password directly in the DB via phpMyAdmin?

FWIW, I also ran into this problem using a Craft demo site.

Comment: The demo sites are running an older (2.3) build of Craft and this was a bug that's been fixed since then. I'll make a note to update the demo sites to run the latest, but going to go ahead and vote to close as a bug report.  Thanks for pointing it out, though!

Comment: Ok, good to know. However, I'm running v2.4 on my site, so why I am still experiencing the bug?

Comment: Ahh, nevermind. I forgot we disabled access to `phpmail` on the demo box to prevent it from turning into a SPAM relay so nothing email related will work.

Comment: So how can I reset the password on my site? The default "Forget your password?" functionality isn't working. Can I just reset my password directly in the DB's "user" table via phpMyAdmin? If I do that, are there any potential issues I should be aware of before I start?

Comment: You can update the `password` column in the `craft_users` table in the database, but I though we were referring to http://demo.buildwithcraft.com, no? Just create a new demo site?

Comment: No, sorry for the confusion. I first encountered the problem on my site. Then, as a test, I also set up a demo site to see if it was just something with my installation or not.

I encountered the issue on both sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your local installation if your check the "Password Reset Required" button for a user and you get a 500 Internal Server Error the next time that users logs in, there is about a 99% chance that email isn't configured/installed correctly on your server.

You can verify this by checking the `craft/storage/runtime/logs` files for the underlying error message.

Craft's email settings are managed under Settings->Email in the control panel.

When you tested on http://demo.buildwithcraft.com and saw the same behavior, that's because we specifically disabled all email functionality on the demo sites in order to prevent them from turning into SPAM relays.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Upon some further investigation, that was indeed the case.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by logging into the DB, going to the "craft_users" table, and changing the value of the "passwordResetRequired" column from "1" to "0".

After I did that, I could log in without any problems.